# VM doesn't work anymore after umount an lv

Tags: linux, openstack, mount, lvm

i'm not a system administrator so i think that i made a big mistake!
we had a problem of storage distribution on VMs in the openstack private cloud.
So i took one VM to reduce the storage and i tried first to execute `lvreduce` to reduce the logical volume but it asks me to `umount` the lv before.
So i run `umount <path-of-my-lv> -l` 
and after that i have not access to vms on ssh even when i rebooted it from the openstack dashboard.

I got this Error when i tried to connect using ssh as usual

**Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection**

any propositioin please ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bad entry on `/etc/fstab` so the VM doesn't boot anymore.

By commenting the bad line and restart the machine, it works again and after that you could correct the mounts and lvms.